# Scheduling a future version of AWS S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to queue up a collection of new versions of web site assets, and make them all go live at nearly the same time.

I've got a series of related files and directories that need to go live at a future time, all at once. In other words, a collection of AWS S3 files in a given bucket need to be updated at nearly the same time. Some of these files are large, and they could originate from locations where Internet access is unreliable and slow. That means they need to be staged somewhere, possibly in another bucket.

I want to be able to roll back to previous version(s) of individual files, or a set of files.

Suggestions or ideas? Bash code is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put **Amazon CloudFront** in front of the Amazon S3 bucket. The CloudFront distribution can be "pointed" to an origin, such as an S3 bucket and path.

So, the update could be done just by changing one configuration in the CloudFront distribution.

If you are sticking with S3 exclusively, the updated files would need to be copied to the appropriate location (either from another bucket or from elsewhere in the same bucket). The time to make this happen would depend upon the size of the objects. You could do a parallel copy to make them copy faster.

Or, if the data is being accessed via a web page, then you could have the new version of the files already in place, then just update the web page that references the files. This means that all the pages (with different names) could be sitting there ready to be used and you just update the home page, which points to the other pages. Think of it as directing people through a different front door.

Comment: I am using CloudFront already, so I am familiar with it. Your CloudFront solution would be good for a scenario where all files are updated, or all files are copied in the new bucket and the old bucket. These are big files, so storage costs would become a factor. The 2nd option would not be an instant switch. The 3rd option would require name mapping - so the webapp would need to be aware of the mapping change for the update. Need to think about that.